# Flashing bios chip with i/o ports?

Tags: laptop, bios, ports

I'm using lenovo b490 laptop. recently bios failed on my laptop. Blank screen appears when i turned on my laptop. I'm trying to flash bios from the usb or other i/o ports. Is there any way to flash bios from i/o ports?.